# To set ContentTypes or MediaTypes to `image/jpeg` in Akka

Tags: scala, http-headers, akka, httpentity

I'm trying to make a test in akka with Scala. I need to test if some image is ".jpeg". I my function, I've to see the ContentType -> MediaType. And in the function it's not a problem 'cause I get the image from the Computer, but to test I've to create a "Mock up".

I was trying first with ContentTypes:

```
val httpResponse = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`,"image")
```

but the problem is, that it should be `image/jpeg` and not `text/...` but there's not that option.

Then, I was trying:

```
val httpResponse = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`image/jpeg`, )
```

And that's pretty nice, but I don't know what to write after the comma. I don't even know, if it's so.

I was looking [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.3/java/http/http-model.html) but I didn't find an answer.

And I saw another posts, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431045/akka-http-how-to-set-response-headers) but I didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer for my question.

with:

```
val httpResponse = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`image/jpeg`, )
```

after the comma should come an Array Byte.

In my case, it works so:

```
val httpResponse = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`image/gif`, new Array[Byte](3))
```

'Cause for me it doesn't matter wich image I've. But if for you is important the image, than, you can create an Array[Byte] of your image, and that's it.

And the most interesting thing is that `httpResponse.contentType` works and inside `contentType` is a `mediaType`

Hope it can help someone.